# Angular router animation doesn't query the class

Tags: css, angular, animation, router

I try to animate 3 classes in my component which will leave the DOM when the route is chaning. I used the setup from the angular doc like:

```
<div [@routeAnimations]="prepareRoute(outlet)">
 <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In the router module I'm passing data with a key of animation into the router, so that I'm able to catch it with the `transition` function in my animation function.

```
export const routerAnimation = trigger('routeAnimations', [
  transition('Welcome => References', [
    query(
      '.state2',
      [
        style({
          zIndex: 12,
          opacity: 0.5
        }),
        animate('1s')
      ],
      { optional: true }
    )
  ])
]);
```

But he goes directly to the references page without doing anything.
The welcome page what I would like to animate got a simple html like so:

```
<section>
  <div class="state0"></div>
  <div class="state1"></div>
  <div class="state2"></div>
  <div class="state4"></div>
  <div class="state5"></div>
</section>
```

The different divs holding different background images. What I would like to achieve here is that when I'm going from the welcome page to the references page, first show .state1 after 0.5s show .state2. The divs are stacked upon each other. So by entering the page you only see the .state0 div. My corresponding scss file looks like so:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

section{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.state0 {
  z-index: 9;
  background-image: url("/assets/images/state0.jpg");
}
```

But I'm not able to query any class and set it to a different z-index. Its working manually with chrome dev tool, when I'm assigning a different z-index to the div of .state1 for instance.
All tough if I set the transition to `Welcome <=> References` first I see the div of .state2 and then it animates to the div .state0. So I guess I'm missing here a crucial basic concept, but I'm stuck for weeks now.

Comment: Are you sure ?, you are returning the outlet and route data in function **prepareRoute()** as shown here https://angular.io/guide/route-animations